# Do redstone lamps work underwater?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

In preparation for TU12 on minecraft Xbox 360 edition,which adds redstonelamps, I've decided to make a redstone lamp system with a switch. Some of the lamps will be underwater, so I plan to use a setup like this one:
[image]
Switch is on the left, redstone lamps are the purple blocks, the triangles are repeaters and the blue blocks are water. Would a setup like this work on the PC version or would the water interfere? (I'm assuming the PC redstone lamps will have the same properties as the Xbox ones).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, redstone lamps work well underwater, *but* light does not travel as far in water as it does in air; it falls by three levels per block it travels through, instead of one; so you might want more lamps so you don't lose the full light effect.

Comment: Perfect! This'll make my circuitry alot less complicated than if I had to do it above ground

Comment: Such a pity I have no time to draw a proper [circuitry alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.ru/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)! :-)

Comment: Oh sorry :p. English isn't my first language so bear with me.

Comment: No sweat, we're here to help, in a funny way :-)